# URL Rewrite - Redirect to different port and changing URL using map

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I want to rewrite URL to redirect to different port, based on HTTP_URL while preserving rest of URL and query string (if specified). 
For example,
`http://host/john/page.aspx` should be redirected to `http://host:1900/page.aspx,`
`http://host/paul/anotherpage.aspx?query` to `http://host:1901/anotherpage.aspx?query`
and `http://host/ringo` to `http://host:1902/`
I've added bunch of rules for every allowed port, but it does not look efficient or manageable.
I'm trying to employ map, (ie john->1900, paul->1901) but cannot figure out how to assemble desired URL.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It took some fiddling to get it working but looking back at it the solutions is quite simple and elegant.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Redirect known names to ports" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/(.*?)/(.*)" />
                <add input="{NameToPort:{C:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}:{C:3}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
    <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="NameToPort">
            <add key="john" value="1900" />
            <add key="paul" value="1901" />
            <add key="ringo" value="1902" />
        </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.