# rewrite url to url:port number

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5

how can I rewrite the next url request:

```
http://mydomain.com/virtualDirectory/default.aspx?param1=2&param2=car
```

to:

```
http://mydomain.com:8888/virtualDirectory/default.aspx?param1=2&param2=car
```

Best regards.

Comment: You should use, a reverse proxy for this job. For example varnish can relay your requests to any host:port.

Comment: and what aboout with just iis server?

Comment: I believe, Marco Miltenburg's answer will do the job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should install the [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and the [ARR (Application Request Routing)](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) modules for IIS. Here are two links on how these can work together to create a reverse proxy to do what you want:

- [Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request
  Routing](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing)
- [Setting up a Reverse Proxy using IIS, URL Rewrite and
  ARR](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx)

Comment: hi there, thank you for answer. I already had that installed and now my issue is solved. thank you anyway.

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly that and that's why I'm having the same issue. The urlrewrite rule is the cause of the "dangerous url" error because of the :portnumber in the rule. I can almost imagine a solution using the first answer at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189505/url-rewrite-redirect-to-different-port-and-changing-url-using-map