# In IIS, can I use the same base path for multiple Web API applications?

Tags: iis, deployment, asp.net-web-api, servicestack

Is there any way to have multiple, independent iis websites that all use the same URL base path?

I have a Web API application that contains http webservices grouped by domain (order, product, shipping, etc...). I want to break those domains into individual API applications so that I can deploy them individually. The only problem is that I don't know how I'd deploy these to iis without having a different url path for each API application.

For example, currently (since every web service is in a single WEB API application), if i want to use the order API, i simply use

```
 http://localhost/api/order/{order-id}
```

If i were to break apart the application into smaller web applications (1 per domain), is there any way i can continue to use

```
http://localhost/api
```

as my base path? Or will I have to use something like:

```
http://localhost/OrderApi/order/{order-id}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reverse Proxying / Url Rewriting to different ServiceStack instances

An elegant option is to separate them into distinct Services and conceptually have them appear under the same url structure by using a reverse proxy or [rewrite rules in IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) which will let you have different top-level paths mapped to different independent ServiceStack instances, e.g:

- http://api.domain.com/productA -> http://localhost:8000
- http://api.domain.com/productB -> http://localhost:8001
- http://api.domain.com/productC -> http://localhost:8002

Comment: Is it possible a rewrite rule maps an url with port 80 on another url with a different port?

Comment: @labilbe You can do it using a reverse proxy like [Application Request Routing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13551165/85785). Otherwise if subdomains are ok, it's easier to just use separate Virtual Hosts/Websites in IIS for each ASP.NET WebApplication.

Comment: Interesting. Does that mean we can handle https on two sites (so two certificates) on the same port of the same machine ?

Comment: @labilbe You can terminate SSL at the reverse proxy and communicate with clear text to downstream servers, IIS refers to this as [SSL offloading](http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/archive/2008/07/10/ssl-off-loading-in-application-request-routing.aspx). ARR should also be able to handle multiple SSL certs for different sites but that would require clients to support [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

Comment: I have the same requirement and your solution does provide an elegant way but what if all the web APIs need to be HTTPS in other words use the same 443 port ? How would the mapping work then ?