# Asp.net Core replace port to text

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I have a site made in Asp.Net Core 3. When it is called via the url www.sitename.com/site it is redirected to my server IIS to myserver.com:8009.

Is it possible to configure IIS or Asp.Net Core to replace the name of port 8809 to name of site like myserver.com/site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rewrite url to url:port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529307/rewrite-url-to-urlport-number)

Answer (score 0):

You can try redirecting www.sitename.com/site to myserver.com/site, and then rewrite myserver.com/site as myserver.com:8009.

Here is my tested code:

```
 <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.sitename.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://myserver.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="rewrite2">
                <match url="site" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://myserver.com:8009." />
            </rule>
```